# Get all dates in calendar in current month

Tags: java, android, date

[image]

How to get all dates in the calendar in current/some month?
for example for this month, like the picture

So the result is ["07-31-2016", "08-01-2016", "08-02-2016" ... "08-31-2016", "09-01-2016", "09-02-2016", "09-03-2016"]

Any ideas?, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: I am beginner in java, i am asking because i don;t know where should i start, thank you for replying.

Comment: Look into classes `Calendar` and/or `GregorianCalendar`. Find the week that contains the first of the month. Find the last day of the month (28, 29, 30 or 31 depending) and the week it is in. For all weeks between the two, inclusive, find all the days of the week.

Comment: It seems your week begins on Sunday. Should the solution take into account that in many calendars the week begins on either Saturday or Monday?

Comment: Every beginner in java can use google unless google is unavailable in your location.

Comment: @OleV.V. afaik no, look at the comments in my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, with [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and its constants you can achieve this quite easy:

Given `month` and `year` get first day of the month and place calendar on monday:

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(MONTH, month - 1);  // month is 0 based on calendar
start.set(YEAR, year);
start.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
start.getTime();   // to avoid problems getTime make set changes apply
start.set(DAY_OF_WEEK, SUNDAY);
if (start.get(MONTH) <= (month - 1))  // check if sunday is in same month!
    start.add(DATE, -7);
```

Given `month` and `year` get last day of month and move calendar to sunday

```
Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.set(MONTH, month);  // next month 
end.set(YEAR, year);
end.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
end.getTime();   // to avoid problems getTime make set changes apply
end.set(DATE, -1);
end.set(DAY_OF_WEEK, SATURDAY);
if (end.get(MONTH) != month)  
    end.add(DATE, + 7);
```

**Test it:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int month = 8, year = 2016; 

    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.set(MONTH, month - 1);  // month is 0 based on calendar
    start.set(YEAR, year);
    start.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    start.getTime();
    start.set(DAY_OF_WEEK, SUNDAY);
    if (start.get(MONTH) <= (month - 1))  
        start.add(DATE, -7);

    System.out.println(printCalendar(start));

    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.set(MONTH, month);  // next month 
    end.set(YEAR, year);
    end.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    end.getTime();
    end.set(DATE, -1);
    end.set(DAY_OF_WEEK, SATURDAY);
    start.getTime();
    if (end.get(MONTH) != month)  
        end.add(DATE, + 7);

    System.out.println(printCalendar(end));
}
```

Combined with:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*;
```

and

```
private final static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
private static String printCalendar(Calendar c) {
    return df.format(c.getTime()); 
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2016/07/31
2016/09/03
```

**WITH**

```
int month = 5, year = 2015;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2015/04/26
2015/06/06
```

Now, just iterate over starting `Calendar` adding `+1` to `Calendar.DATE` in a `while` loop (in the example I split by weeks to be more clear):

```
int i = 1;
while (start.before(end)) {
    System.out.print(printCalendar(start));
    if (i % 7 == 0) {   // last day of the week
        System.out.println();
        i  = 1;
    } else {
        System.out.print(" - ");
        i++;
    }
    start.add(DATE, 1);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2015/04/26 - 2015/04/27 - 2015/04/28 - 2015/04/29 - 2015/04/30 - 2015/05/01 - 2015/05/02
2015/05/03 - 2015/05/04 - 2015/05/05 - 2015/05/06 - 2015/05/07 - 2015/05/08 - 2015/05/09
2015/05/10 - 2015/05/11 - 2015/05/12 - 2015/05/13 - 2015/05/14 - 2015/05/15 - 2015/05/16
2015/05/17 - 2015/05/18 - 2015/05/19 - 2015/05/20 - 2015/05/21 - 2015/05/22 - 2015/05/23
2015/05/24 - 2015/05/25 - 2015/05/26 - 2015/05/27 - 2015/05/28 - 2015/05/29 - 2015/05/30
2015/05/31 - 2015/06/01 - 2015/06/02 - 2015/06/03 - 2015/06/04 - 2015/06/05 - 2015/06/06
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but isn't usually calendar start with sunday and end in saturday? just asking.

Comment: maybe in your country, not in Spain... anyway... it will be easy to you to adapt it to your needs

Comment: Thank you, btw, do i need to check when i using it for January or December? when set month for start and end?

Comment: btw i have to remove line if (start.get(MONTH) <= (month - 1)) or it will show a week earlier

Answer (score 4):

## java.time

You can use the nice [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. Both the above solutions work, this is a way to do in Java 8. Can be done with a little more brevity , split it just for understanding.

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Clazz {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate firstDayOfTheMonth = today.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
        LocalDate lastDayOfTheMonth = today.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
        LocalDate squareCalendarMonthDayStart = firstDayOfTheMonth
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
        LocalDate squareCalendarMonthDayEnd = lastDayOfTheMonth
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY));
        List<LocalDate> totalDates = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!squareCalendarMonthDayStart.isAfter(squareCalendarMonthDayEnd)) {
            totalDates.add(squareCalendarMonthDayStart);
            squareCalendarMonthDayStart = squareCalendarMonthDayStart.plusDays(1);
        }

        totalDates.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the monday before the 1st of that month:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
c.set(2016, 08, 01);

Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
start.setWeekDate(2016,c.getWeekYear(), Calendar.MONDAY);
```

Get the sunday after the last day of that month:

```
c.set(2016,08,31);
Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
end.setWeekDate(2016, c.getWeekYear(), Calendar.SUNDAY);
```

Then print all dates between start and end

Answer (score 1):

Write a common method like this and use it -

```
 fun getAllDateOfCurrentMonth(): List<LocalDate> {
            val yearMonth= YearMonth.now()
            val firstDayOfTheMonth = yearMonth.atDay(1)
            val datesOfThisMonth = mutableListOf<LocalDate>()
            for (daysNo in 0 until yearMonth.lengthOfMonth()){
                datesOfThisMonth.add(firstDayOfTheMonth.plusDays(daysNo.toLong()))
            }
            return datesOfThisMonth
        }
```