# How can I add 30 days from today's date in List

Tags: android, date, datetime, android-spinner

I want to add 30 days from today's date in to spinner so I am adding through ArrayList bt How can I add thirty days to todays date in following for loop

```
 ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int maxDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd");

for (int i = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i <= maxDay; i++)
     {  
             dates.add( df.format(cal.getTime()));
             cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i + 1);
     }
```

Let assume today's day is 29 so it will only prints 29 -Sep and 30-Sep.
If I change i=0 then it will print till maxDay but I want to resrtict user from selecting past date so I am starting from today's date

Second thing how can I dispay today(text) insted of today's date ?

Comment: Something here can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143366/get-all-dates-in-calendar-in-current-month Also you need to format those dates as per your need, create an ArrayList and pass it to Spinner adapter.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi you have any suggestion in this ?